# Can't upload to PyPI: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error>

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm suddenly having issues uploading packages. I'm use to the previous paradigm of registering a package and then uploading. Now, it seems as if the registration is suddenly no longer necessary and that I now require a ~/.pypirc file. I've set .pypirc like so (from https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/packageindex.html#pypirc):

```
[distutils] # this tells distutils what package indexes you can push to
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: *USERNAME*
password: *PASSWORD*

[pypitest]
repository: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username: *USERNAME*
password: *PASSWORD*
```

However, I consistently have issues:

```
...
Creating tar archive
removing 'jsonpare-0.2.10' (and everything under it)
running upload
Password: 
Submitting dist/jsonpare-0.2.10.tar.gz to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
error: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error>
```

It's prompting me for a password even though I've provide the password in the config, and I get an SSL issue every time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @phd was valid. Upgraded tool and used Twine.